# Vue router nav has gap when scrollable on one page application v-navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, navigation-drawer

[gap at bottom of nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7AEd.png)
Any advice would be helpful to make this side nav remove the gap at the bottom of the v-navigation-drawer. In Default VUE I have this code. I'm using NUXT and VUE router

```
    <template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      color="#0d354c"
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app 
    >
    
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using VUE router and nuxt there is your default.vue page. You must set fixed to true instead of false by default.

```
  fixed: true,
```